# OS\Cordova Permissions Error > "Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir"

Tags: ios, cordova, npm

When I run 'cordova build ios' on an existing project I get a permissions error when accessing the projects ios folder.

Node has been installed using 'NVM' and when I run 'which cordova' and it gives me the correct path in the .nvm folder.

I'm also able to install npm packages without sudo and can run 'cordova build ios' on on other projects no problem.

**Error printed in the terminal:**

cordova-custom-config: Skipping auto-restore of config file backup(s)

Error: EACCES: permission denied, scandir '/Users/username/project/cordova/platforms/ios/build/device/libCordova.a'

The last resort I can think is removing the ios platform and adding again, but the last dev may have made some changes to these files so would like to avoid that if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error but for many other files, all when running 'cordova build ios'.  The files in question were all in the same folder, all owned by 'root'.  I am pretty sure that I had previously and mistakenly run 'sudo cordova build ios', which would have generated the files initially.
I ran a 'sudo chown -R [me] [folder]' and got my build back.